# Redux-Form initial values from

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I'm trying to fill the profile form with data from API. Unfortunately redux-form doesn't want to cooperate with me in this case. For some reason fields stays empty whatever I do.

Setting the fixed values instead of values passed from reducer work well for some reason.

Maybe this is because I'm using **redux-promise** for API calls inside the action creators? How can I live with it and get rid of this. Here is my form component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchRoleList, fetchUserData } from '../actions';

class UserEdit extends Component {

    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.fetchRoleList();
        this.props.fetchUserData();
    }

    handleEditProfileFormSubmit(formProps) {
        console.log(formProps);
    }

    getRoleOptions(selected_id) {
        if (!this.props.profile) {
            return <option>No data</option>;
        }

        return this.props.profile.roles.map(role => {
            return <option key={role.role_id} value={role.role_id}>{role.name}</option>;
        });
    }

    renderField(props) {
        const { input, placeholder, label, value, type, meta: { touched, error } } = props;
        return (
        <fieldset className={`form-group ${ (touched && error) ? 'has-error' : '' }`}>
            <label>{label}</label>
            <input className="form-control" {...input} type={type} placeholder={placeholder} />
            {touched && error && <div className="error">{error}</div>}
        </fieldset>
        );
    }

    renderSelect({ input, placeholder, options, label, type, meta: { touched, error } }) {
        return (
        <fieldset className={`form-group ${ (touched && error) ? 'has-error' : '' }`}>
            <label>{label}</label>
            <select className="form-control" {...input}>
                {options}
            </select>
            {touched && error && <div className="error">{error}</div>}
        </fieldset>
        );
    }

    render() {
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

        const user = this.props.profile.user;

        return (
        <div> {user ? user.email : ''}
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.handleEditProfileFormSubmit.bind(this))}>
                <Field name="email" label="Email:" component={this.renderField} type="text" placeholder="email@gmail.com" className="form-control"/>
                <Field name="name" label="Name:"  component={this.renderField} type="text" placeholder="John Doe" className="form-control"/>
                <Field name="role" label="Role:" component={this.renderSelect} type="select" className="form-control" options={this.getRoleOptions()}/>
                <button action="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Edit user</button>

                <Field name="password" label="Password:" component={this.renderField} type="password" className="form-control"/>
                <Field name="passwordConfirm" label="Confirm Password:" component={this.renderField} type="password" className="form-control"/>
                { this.props.errorMessage
                &&  <div className="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong>Oops!</strong> {this.props.errorMessage}
                    </div> }
                <button action="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Sign up!</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        );
    }

}

let InitializeFromStateForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'initializeFromState'
})(UserEdit);

InitializeFromStateForm = connect(
  state => ({
    profile: state.profile,
    initialValues: state.profile.user
  }),
  { fetchRoleList, fetchUserData }
)(InitializeFromStateForm);

export default InitializeFromStateForm;
```

I do believe action creator will be useful as well:

```
export function fetchUserData(user_id) {
    user_id = user_id ? user_id : '';

    const authorization = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const request = axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}/user/${user_id}`, {
      headers: { authorization }
    });

    return {
        type: FETCH_USER,
        payload: request
    };
}
```

Comment: So is the problem that although your initialValues props get changed, your form does not get populated with the new data right?

Comment: Well not really. I Want to initially fill form with data from reducer and doesn't care about reducer later on.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You need to add `enableReinitialize: true` as below.

```
let InitializeFromStateForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'initializeFromState',
    enableReinitialize : true // this is needed!!
})(UserEdit)
```

If your initialValues prop gets updated, your form will update too.

Comment: Yes! This is it! Thank you it helped me a lot!

Comment: Spent 3 hours searching. So hard to find but `enableReinitialize : true` did the job. Thanks for that.

Comment: I am not even going to admit the amount of time i wasted today fighting with this. You sure are a hero!

Comment: Man, you saved me! Thank you sooo much!

Comment: Man I spent like three hours on this. Thanks!

Comment: ohh man, but that documentation, spent couple of hours on that :(

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH i've been hunting for this answer for hours and hours!

Comment: Yes. it works. it's so strange I didn't find it in official doc

Comment: FWIW, `enableReinitialize` is documented [here](https://redux-form.com/7.1.1/docs/api/reduxform.md/) along with other config properties you can pass in to `reduxForm`.

Comment: This was added in [6.0.0-rc.1](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/releases/tag/v6.0.0-rc.1)

Comment: I wove uuuuuuuu

Answer (score 7):

To set the `initialValues` it is important to apply the `reduxForm()` decorator **before** the `connect()` decorator from redux. The fields will not populate from the store state if the order of the decorators is inverted.

```
const FormDecoratedComponent = reduxForm(...)(Component)
const ConnectedAndFormDecoratedComponent = connect(...)(FormDecoratedComponent)
```

If, in addition to setting the values for the first time, you need to re-populate the form every time the state changes then set `enableReinitialize: true`

Find a simple example in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48875889/2188595).

Read the official [documentation and full example](https://redux-form.com/7.2.3/examples/initializefromstate/).

Read about this issue [here](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/621).

Answer (score 2):

So, you're trying:

- Load API data into the form
- Update the form just on load (aka. `initialValues`)

Whilst @FurkanO might work, I think the best approach is to load the form when you got all async data, you can do that by creating a parent component / container:

UserEditLoader.jsx

```
componentDidMount() {
  // I think this one fits best for your case, otherwise just switch it to
  // componentDidUpdate
  apiCalls();
}
/* api methods here */
render() {
 const { profile } = this.props;
 return (
   {profile && <UserEdit profile={profile} />}
 );
}
```

Basically what you should be doing in the `UserEditLoader` is to execute the API functions and update the state (or props if redux connected). Whenever the profile variable isn't empty (meaning you got the data you were expecting) then mount `UserEdit` with profile as prop.

Answer (score 1):

initialize() is a prop provided by reduxForm, that can be used to fill up the form values.

change() is another prop provided by reduxFrom to change a field value.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const submit = values => {
    // print the form values to the console
    console.log(values)
}

interface Props {
    history?: any;
    location?: any;
    session?: any;
    handleSubmit?: Function;
    initialize?: Function;
    change?: Function;
}

class ContactForm extends React.Component<Props, any> {
constructor(props, state) {
    super(props, state);
    this.state = {
        value: ''
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    const { initialize, session, location } = this.props;

    console.log(location.pathname);

    if (session && session.user) {
        const values = {
            firstName: session.user.name,
            lastName: session.user.lastName,
            email: session.user.email
        };
        initialize(values);
    }
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { initialize, session } = this.props;

    if (nextProps.session !== session) {
        if (nextProps.session && nextProps.session.user) {
            const values = {
                firstName: nextProps.session.user.name,
                lastName: nextProps.session.user.lastName,
                email: nextProps.session.user.email
            };
            initialize(values);
        } else {
            const values = {
                firstName: null,
                lastName: null,
                email: null
            };
            initialize(values);
        }
    }
}

render() {
    const { handleSubmit, change } = this.props;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                    <Field name="firstName" component="input" type="text" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                    <Field name="lastName" component="input" type="text" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                    <Field name="email" component="input" type="email" />
                </div>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>



            <input type="text" value={this.state.value}
                onChange={(e) => {
                    this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
                    change('firstName', e.target.value);
                }}
            />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
}

export default connect((state) => {
    return {
        session: state.session
    }
},
{}
)(withRouter((reduxForm({
    form: 'contact'
})(ContactForm))));
```

Comment: when using `props.initialize()` to initialize the form with my initial values I am unable to get the updated formValues in `handleFormSubmit(formValues)` but i am able to do this when connecting `initialValues` with a store containing the initialValues

Answer (score 0):

If the `enableReinitialize : true` trick does not work, you can update each field when the `initialValues` prop changes.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { change, initialValues } = this.props
    const values = nextProps.initialValues;

    if(initialValues !== values){
        for (var key in values) {
            if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                change(key,values[key]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have never worked with `FieldsArray` but I assume this would not work here.

Answer (score -1):

For a stateless functional component, you can do it like this:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.initialize({ discountCodes: ["ABC200", "XYZ500"] });
}
```

For a class, you can do it like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => (
  {
    initialValues: {
      discountCodes: ["ABC200", "XYZ500"]
  }
);
```