# Redux-Form Initial values

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

So I'm trying to load a Redux Form pre populated with values from my store. However I'm unable to get anything back other than `null`. Been at this for several hours now and been reading over several SO examples trying different things and think I'm just at a wall on this.

Following this [Redux Form Initializing from State example](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/initializeFromState/)

- Redux: 3.6.0
- React-Redux: 5.0.3
- Redux-Form: 6.6.3
- React: 15.4.2

There is a parent component that is rendering a child component which is the form. For sake of brevity going to put in the bare minimum of code and make names as generic as possible. Everything loads fine but I think the issue relies in not properly connecting to my store. Or rather I should just be loading the data on a `componentWillMount`?

**Parent Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchUser } from '../actions/usersActions';

import ChildForm from './ChildForm.jsx'

@connect((store) => {
  return{
    user: store.users.user
  }
})

export default class Parent extends Component{
  componentWillMount(){
    this.props.dispatch(fetchUser(this.props.match.params.id))
  }
  submit = (values) => {//do some stuff}

  render(){
    return(
      <ChildForm onSubmit={this.submit} />
    );
  }
}
```

**ChildForm:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import { user } from './reducers/usersReducer.js';

class ChildForm extends Component{
  render(){
    console.log('FORM STATE >>>>>>>>>>', this.state); //Returns NULL
    const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return(
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
          <Field name="first_name" component="input" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }    
}

ChildForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'childForm',
  enableReinitialize : true // I found this in another SO Example
})(ChildForm);

ChildForm = connect(
  state => ({
    user: state.user,
    initialValues: state.user
  }),
  { fetchUser }
)(ChildForm)

export default ChildForm;
```

[enableReinitialize SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267037/redux-form-initial-values-from)

**usersReducer.js**

```
export default function reducer(state={
  user: {},
}, action){
  switch (action.type){
    case "FETCH_USER_FULFILLED":{
      return{
        ...state,
        user: action.payload
      }
    }
  }
  return state;
}
```

So this is where I'm at currently. Can get the page, form, and submit all work. However I can't seem to figure out how to get my Store values out and into the form fields. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like everything is wired up correctly but I wasn't pulling in the correct object in the store.

```
ChildForm = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: state.users.user
  }),
  { fetchUser }
)(ChildForm)
```

...Always something little