# Redux Form - initialValues not set on page load

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I am having some issues with setting the inital form field values using redux-form.

Here is the code I tried

```
import { Field, FieldArray, reduxForm, getFormValues, change } from 'redux-form'

const renderField = ({
  input,
  label,
  type,
  meta: { asyncValidating, touched, error }
}) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div className={asyncValidating ? 'async-validating' : ''}>
      <input {...input} type={type} placeholder={label}/>
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
)
class Profile extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null,
    }
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchProfile();    
  }

  async handleChange(e) {
    await this.setState({ 'initialValues': { [e.target.name] : e.target.value }});
    await this.setState({ [e.target.name] : e.target.value });
  }

onSubmit = (e) => {
    this.props.saveProfile({
      firstName: this.state.auth.firstName,
      lastName: this.state.auth.lastName,
    });
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({ 
      firstName : nextProps.initialValues.firstName,
      lastName : nextProps.initialValues.LastName,
     });

    this.setState({ 'initialValues': {
      firstName : nextProps.initialValues.firstName,
      lastName : nextProps.initialValues.LastName,
     }});
  }
render() {
    return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)}>
          <div>
          <Field
              name="firstName"
              type="text"
              component={renderField}
              label="firstName"
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
          <Field
              name="lastName"
              type="text"
              component={renderField}
              label="lastName"
              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>
              Update Info
            </button>
          </div>
    </form>
);
  }
}

Profile = reduxForm({
  form: 'Profile' ,
 // fields,
  validate,
  asyncValidate,
  enableReinitialize: true,
})(Profile);

function mapStateToProps(state, props){
  let firstName = '';
  let lastName = '';
  return {
    userData: state.auth.userData,
    initialValues:{
      firstName: state.auth.firstName,
      lastName: state.auth.lastName,
    }
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchProfile: () => dispatch(auth.actions.fetchProfile()),
  }
} 

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Profile);
```

But it is not setting value in field when load. field is just empty

Comment: Getting API response and values are updating correctly in `componentWillReceiveProps`? Have you tried changing these values to `value={this.state.firstName ?? ''}` to `value={this.state.firstName || ''}`?

Comment: @PrathapReddy: whenever i change value, handleChange is calling and key value is proper though state is not updating

Comment: Did the answer helped you finally? If not, requesting you to post your solution to help others with similar issue. Thanks. @bhumi-shah

Comment: @PrathapReddy Yes answer helped and that's why accepted!! You should add formprops comment into answer as it may help others to fix same issue

Comment: I haven't received bounty for this hence I have [questioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399844/why-bounty-has-not-awarded-though-the-answer-is-accepted-by-author) it in `meta` to understand the process of `bounty`. Posted my previous comment to know if it actually helped you or not as per `answerers` comments in `meta` question. Anyway no offence. Just wanted to know why I missed `bounty`. Thanks for clarification. :-)

Comment: @PrathapReddy I thought i accepted answer so you got bounty points. Let me check though

Comment: Let it go this time. We can't do anything with the **existing process**. Please remember to award it manually (We will get 7 days to do this - 6 days of bounty period + 1 days grace period) rather than the **auto job** takes over it and **decide what to do** from next time. Anyways, the answer helped you with the `problem`. I am glad for that. I will get reputations daily upon my participation hence least bothered about it. I have **questioned on the bounty process/system awarding process** in `meta` discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `Redux Form` works little different.

You don't need to set explicit `onChange` handler or declare any state to hold form `fields` data in `Redux Form`. Update your code similar to below

```js
import { Field, FieldArray, reduxForm, getFormValues, change } from 'redux-form'

const renderField = ({
  input,
  label,
  type,
  meta: { asyncValidating, touched, error }
}) => (
  <div>
    <label>{label}</label>
    <div className={asyncValidating ? 'async-validating' : ''}>
      <input {...input} type={type} placeholder={label}/>
      {touched && error && <span>{error}</span>}
    </div>
  </div>
)
class Profile extends Component {
  // No need constructor/to explicitly declare the state
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchProfile();    
  }

render() {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, submitting} = props; // You can have custom handleSubmit too
    return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div>
          <Field
              name="firstName"
              type="text"
              component={renderField}
              label="firstName"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
          <Field
              name="lastName"
              type="text"
              component={renderField}
              label="lastName"
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>
              Update Info
            </button>
          </div>
    </form>
);
  }
}

Profile = reduxForm({
  form: 'Profile' ,
 // fields,
  validate,
  asyncValidate,
  enableReinitialize: true,
})(Profile);

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
    userData: state.auth.userData,
    initialValues:{ // These are the initial values. You can give any name here for testing to verify the ReduxForm working
      firstName: state.auth.firstName,
      lastName: state.auth.lastName,
    }
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchProfile: () => dispatch(auth.actions.fetchProfile()),
  }
} 

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Profile);
```

The example in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41267037/redux-form-initial-values-from) and the `answer` would definitely help you to understand things better.

Comment: This is still creating issue.

Comment: Are you getting any issues in the `console` while `handleChange` is execute on typing?

Comment: updated componentWillReceiveProps and set handleChange to async. See updated code

Comment: When I click on submit, it gets previous value instead of new value

Comment: No need to change `handleChange` async. Can you just try with the 2 changes. 1) Constructor binding as suggested in answer. 2) simple mapping in onChange like this  `onChange={this.handleChange}`

Comment: If i remove async from handleChange, it is not updating state and componentWillReceiveProps return old value

Comment: Do you think, there is an issue in initialValues

Comment: Nope. `initialValues` thing looks good to me. Let me check the `Redux Form` docs which I didn't use much. Will update you if I found something helpful.

Comment: is there any issue in validate? because it is not stopping form to submit

Comment: You need to pass `validate` function which perform validations to stop form `submit`. This [redux async form change docs](https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/examples/asyncchangevalidation) has detailed explanation on how async form change works. BTW, updated my answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Okay but I am still getting issue in passing value from state. mapStateToProps is gettiing older one

Comment: Able to render form with initial values just by hardcoding as suggested in answer instead of reading from `state.auth`? And able get anything help from docs [using state rendering](https://redux-form.com/8.3.0/examples/initializefromstate)??

Comment: hardcoded value doesn't work with redux-form <Field

Comment: I mean having `initialValues` - firstName: 'Test', lastName: 'User' etc.. in `mapStateToProps` is showing those custom values in UI?

Comment: Yes it is showing in ui but when handleChange on onSubmit, I am not getting updated value

Comment: As suggested in code snippet in my answer, the on change/`handleChange` is not required for redux form. For `onSubmit` you need to use the redux-form `props` handleSubmit as per the example question I have mentioned in my answer. You can log the updated form values on custom `handleSubmit` as per the link in my answer.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge on `ReduxForm`. Suggested solutions based on my `React/Redux` knowledge. Please post your working answer once you are able to get the desired behaviour. Thanks 

Comment: I am using handleSubmit, see updated code in question. Though same issue

Comment: Tried removing `onChange` prop on `Field` component? Able to the name changes in your `onSubmit` method upon submit click? `oSubmit = (formProps) => { console.log(formProps); }`!?